# FillbyToolStipButton_Click cannot convert "" to integer

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ctype

In my VB form, I used a bounded datagridview to manage my database table. I create FillBy() query with 2 parameters : int1, int2 . Both are integer.
When some controls are changed, I call sub Anychange() in order to trigger FillByToolStipButton_Click. But it seem the two parameters not changed, the error message occured in Sub FillByToolStipButton_Click :"Convertion from string "" to type integer is not valid"
Please advise. Thank.
Belows some parts of my code

```
   Private Sub FillByToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FillByToolStripButton.Click
    Try
         Me.Before_CloseTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.BeforeCloseDataSet.Before_Close, CType(int1ToolStripTextBox.Text, Integer), CType(int2ToolStripTextBox.Text, Integer))
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Fillby - " + ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

 Private Sub AnyChanged()
    Try
        int1StripTextBox.Text = CType(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, String)
        int2ToolStripTextBox.Text = CType(ComboBox2.SelectedValue, String)
        FillByToolStripButton_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("AnyChanged - " + ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: And are you sure there are proper inputs (only integers, no decimal points) in the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I solved it.

Just change

```
 Privat Sub AnyChange() to
   Dim a as integer
   dim b as integer
   a = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
   b = ComboBox2.SelectedValue
   Me.Before_CloseTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.BeforeCloseDataSet.Before_Close, a, b)
```